# Adding fixed price item using eBay SOAP-request returning error 37

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

I'm trying to submit a new product using the eBay API, but whatever I try the following error occurs:

> Input data for tag  is invalid or missing.
>   Please check API documentation. (error code 37).

It doesn't show which field in the "ShippingDetails" is invalid. I've tried everything without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:RequesterCredentials>
            <ns1:eBayAuthToken>(hidden)</ns1:eBayAuthToken>
            <ns1:Credentials>
                <ns1:AppId>(hidden)</ns1:AppId>
                <ns1:DevId>(hidden)</ns1:DevId>
                <ns1:AuthCert>(hidden)</ns1:AuthCert>
            </ns1:Credentials>
        </ns1:RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
            <ns1:ErrorLanguage>en_US</ns1:ErrorLanguage>
            <ns1:Version>837</ns1:Version>
            <ns1:Item>
                <ns1:Country>NL</ns1:Country>
                <ns1:Currency>EUR</ns1:Currency>
                <ns1:Description>&lt;div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</ns1:Description>
                <ns1:ListingDuration>GTC</ns1:ListingDuration>
                <ns1:Location>Oirsbeek</ns1:Location>
                <ns1:PaymentMethods>PayPal</ns1:PaymentMethods>
                <ns1:PayPalEmailAddress>info@sfeerleven.nl</ns1:PayPalEmailAddress>
                <ns1:PrimaryCategory>
                    <ns1:CategoryID>11700</ns1:CategoryID>
                </ns1:PrimaryCategory>
                <ns1:Quantity>20</ns1:Quantity>
                <ns1:ShippingDetails>
                    <ns1:ShippingServiceOptions>
                        <ns1:ShippingService>DE_GLSInternational</ns1:ShippingService>
                        <ns1:ShippingServiceCost>5.95</ns1:ShippingServiceCost>
                        <ns1:ShippingServicePriority>1</ns1:ShippingServicePriority>
                        <ns1:FreeShipping>false</ns1:FreeShipping>
                    </ns1:ShippingServiceOptions>
                    <ns1:ShippingType>Flat</ns1:ShippingType>
                </ns1:ShippingDetails>
                <ns1:StartPrice>85.95</ns1:StartPrice>
                <ns1:Title>Clayre &amp;amp; Eef Bett&amp;uuml;berwurf 180x260 | Q103.060</ns1:Title>
                <ns1:VATDetails>
                    <ns1:VATPercent>21</ns1:VATPercent>
                </ns1:VATDetails>
                <ns1:SKU>Q103.060</ns1:SKU>
                <ns1:CategoryBasedAttributesPrefill>true</ns1:CategoryBasedAttributesPrefill>
                <ns1:PostalCode>6438 BB</ns1:PostalCode>
                <ns1:PictureDetails>
                    <ns1:PictureURL>https://sfeerleven.nl/perry/Afbeeldingen/originals/Q103.060.jpg</ns1:PictureURL>
                </ns1:PictureDetails>
                <ns1:DispatchTimeMax>0</ns1:DispatchTimeMax>
                <ns1:ReturnPolicy>
                    <ns1:ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ns1:ReturnsAcceptedOption>
                </ns1:ReturnPolicy>
                <ns1:ConditionID>1000</ns1:ConditionID>
            </ns1:Item>
        </ns1:AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value *DE_GLSInternational* is not a valid shipping service. The services available on eBay do change over time and so the best way to get the latest is as follows.

- Make a call to [GeteBayDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html) for the site that you are listing to.
- In the request ensure that [DetailName](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#Request.DetailName) is set to *ShippingServiceDetails*.
- In the response iterate through each [ShippingServiceDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails) element and check for the existence of [ValidForSellingFlow](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.ValidForSellingFlow).
- If *ValidForSellingFlow* exists and has the value 'true', read in the value of [ShippingService](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.ShippingService).
- You can also check the value of [InternationalService](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails.InternationalService) to see if the service is available for international shipping.

Do not use any of the values that are available in the [official eBay documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html). This page is very out of date and many of the services listed no longer exist.